# Why did wget download to the home directory (Linux) rather than the specified directory?

Tags: linux

I ran the wget command via the terminal for the very first time(linux newbie) and rather than downloading the file to the path I specified i.e. `wget {URI} /home/{username}/Downloads` but it downloaded the file to the path `/home/`. Why is that? Also why do I get the message `/home/{username}/Downloads/: Scheme missing.`

Comment: Why you think that's the way to tell `wget` where to download to? Did you just make that up and hope it would work? Or did you read somewhere that that was the right thing to do?

Comment: @David Schwartz - No I didn't make it up. I thought it would work because most commands expect a source and destination directory.

Comment: I apologize if this comes off as rude, I'm trying to be helpful. You really should not just guess at how to use commands you're not familiar with. And if you do, you should not at all be surprised when it doesn't work. And if you do, and it doesn't work, your first instinct should be to check the documentation to find out how to use the unfamiliar command. This is not intended as a criticism but is genuinely intended to help you get better results in the future.

Comment: @David Schwartz - Not a problem. Always welcome constructive criticisms. I did read the man pages however could not find any indication of whether I could specify a destination directory. It is my fault for assuming I could specify one as all commands I have used to date expect one. My apologies. I would however like to understand why it wrote the file to my home directory as the command `wget` is in the `/usr/bin/` directory and would have thought based on my understand it should write the file to the directory from which the command was executed

Comment: or does it write the file to my current working?

Comment: Current working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` doesn't work like this. It needs the `-O` (read: capital O) parameter if you want to supply a different output file name.

```
wget -O [output-file] [URI]
```

Note that according to [`man wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.  If `-` is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.

So this only works in simple cases where you have one file to download.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't quite follow what you mean by `The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file. If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.` Can you give me an example?

Comment: `wget` allows you to download more than just one file in one go, e.g. with the `--recursive` option. In this case, you obviously can't specify *one* output file :)

Comment: When you say `one` output file, what do you mean? I assume that when you say the `--recursive` command, you mean when for example I would like to download a HTML page and all its related links?

Comment: Exactly right, that's the case I'm talking about. Anyway, `wget` will download to your current (`pwd`) working directory if not specified otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the bash (shell) expression:

```
(cd /home/{username}/Downloads; wget {URI})
```

instead of the invalid `wget {URI} /home/{username}/Downloads`

Another option is to use the `-P` option:

```
-P,  --directory-prefix=PREFIX  save files to PREFIX/...
```

Like this:

```
wget -P /home/{username}/Downloads {URI}
```